# Anybody make sense of these GPUZ readings from my XG Mobile

Tags: laptop, gpu, power, nvidia-graphics-card, throttling

So I have an XG Mobile 3080 that's started acting weird,

Recently it has been stuck at 210MHz regardless of what its doing, by switching power plan to turbo I can achieve 300MHz and with manual mode in the crate software with a 200MHz offset i can achieve 405MHz but nothing past that. Temperature reaches around 70-78 °C when running a game or benchmark and the performance reflects the change in clock speed but pretty sure these are supposed to run in the range of 1500MHhz+.

After further digging I found these weird readings in GPUz, anybody any ideas as to why they're like this?

GPU-Z Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your GPU?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use [Nvidia Inspector](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/nvidia-inspector/#:%7E:text=NVIDIA%20Inspector%20is%20a%20utility,clocks%2C%20temperature%20and%20fan%20speed.) for better readings. You may also change the offset there and overclock your GPU.
**⚠ Use at your own risk!**